# Accessing Data Items on Select with ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net

Writing an asp.net file manager.

Essentially, the user clicks on a folder in a TreeView control and the files within that folder are shown in a ListView control.

**The ListView**

```
<asp:listview id="lvFiles" runat="server" onitemdeleting="lvFiles_ItemDeleting" 
      onselectedindexchanging="lvFiles_SelectedIndexChanging">
     <layouttemplate>
          <table cellpadding="2" width="520px" border="1" id="tbl1" runat="server">
              <tr id="Tr1" runat="server" style="background-color: #98FB98">
                  <th id="Th0" runat="server"></th>
                      <th id="Th1" runat="server">Filename</th>
                      <th id="Th2" runat="server">Uploaded</th>
                      <th id="Th3" runat="server">Last Accessed</th>
              </tr>
              <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
           </table>
           <asp:datapager id="DataPager1" runat="server" pagesize="25">
                <fields>
                    <asp:nextpreviouspagerfield buttontype="Button" />
                </fields>
           </asp:datapager>
      </layouttemplate>
      <emptyitemtemplate>
          <p>No items</p>
      </emptyitemtemplate>
      <itemtemplate>
          <tr runat="server">
              <td><asp:linkbutton id="itemSelected" runat="server" tooltip='<%# Eval("FullName") %>' autopostback="True" commandname="select" text="Select" />
              </td>
              <td><asp:label id="fNameLabel" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:label>
              </td>
          </tr>
       </itemtemplate>
       <selecteditemtemplate>
           <tr id="Tr2" runat="server">
               <td>Selected</td>
               <td><asp:label id="fNameLabel" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:label>
               </td>
               <td><asp:button id="btnDelete" runat="server" text="Delete" commandname="Delete"></asp:button>
               </td>
           </tr>
      </selecteditemtemplate>
</asp:listview>
```

**Binding the File List**

So currently what happens, is in the `TreeView_SelectedNodeChanged` event, the application takes the `DirectoryInfo` object represented by the `TreeNode` and gets an array of `FileInfo` objects, using the `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()` method.

That `FileInfo[]` is passed to the following method.

```
protected void AddFilesToViewPort(FileInfo[] Files)
{
    List<FileInfo> fList = new List<FileInfo>();
    for (int i = 0; i < Files.Length; i++)
    {
        fList.Add(Files[i]);
    }
    lvFiles.DataSource = fList;
    lvFiles.DataBind();
    upExistingFiles.Update();
}
```

Which binds the `FileInfo[]` to the `ListView` object, `lvFiles`, which is pretty much exactly how I want it.

What I want to do is be able to select an item in the ListView (which can be done at the moment) then when the user presses the `Delete` button, I want the application to work with the file in question. Essentially, I want to move the file to a "Deleted Files" directory and log the action in the database.

The problem I'm having is getting the actual `FileInfo` object associated with the list item I select.

If I attach the debugger to the and step through, the `lvFiles_ItemDeleting` event is firing and I'm getting the index of the selected `ListItem` as I should be, but when I go through the objects in the debugger, the actual information about the object the `ListItem` is representing just isn't there.

[image: Image showing lack of DataKeys in the debugged ListView]

As you can see in the image above, the DataKeys property of the `ListView` is holding some information about its items, but when I dig deeper into that property, the information just isn't there.

How do I get the `FileInfo` object from the selected `ListViewItem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this answers your question:

```
ListViewDataItem item = lvFiles.Items[e.ItemIndex];
FileInfo fInfo = (FileInfo)item.DataItem;
```

You also need to specify the DataKeyNames that you want to pass into the listView. something like:

```
<asp:listview DataKeyNames="FullName, Name" id="lvFiles" runat="server" onitemdeleting="lvFiles_ItemDeleting" onselectedindexchanging="lvFiles_SelectedIndexChanging">. read more about it [here][1]
```

Comment: Razvan, thanks for the reply.

Unfortunately, that returns a null FileInfo Object.

Looking further into the `SelectedDataKey` parameter of the `lvFiles` object, I'm seeing the following exception: 

`base {System.Exception} = {"Data keys must be specified on ListView 'lvFiles' before the selected data keys can be retrieved.  Use the DataKeyNames property to specify data keys."}`

Comment: you need to specify the DataKeyNames that you want to pass into the listView. something like: <asp:listview DataKeyNames="FullName, Name" id="lvFiles" runat="server" onitemdeleting="lvFiles_ItemDeleting" onselectedindexchanging="lvFiles_SelectedIndexChanging">. read more about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.datakeynames.aspx

Comment: Frustratingly, if I try to set the DataKeyNames in the codebehind when I bind the data to the ListView, I get an exception which says `"System.IO.FileInfo does not have a property named "FullName"` (which it does). However, if I adjust the ListView declaration in the .aspx file to this: `<asp:listview id="lvFiles" runat="server" onitemdeleting="lvFiles_ItemDeleting" 
                        onselectedindexchanging="lvFiles_SelectedIndexChanging" datakeynames="FullName" >` as you suggested, it is suddenly working. Edit your answer as such, I'll accept it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: how did you assign the DataKeyNames?

Comment: `<asp:listview id="lvFiles" runat="server" onitemdeleting="lvFiles_ItemDeleting"                         onselectedindexchanging="lvFiles_SelectedIndexChanging" datakeynames="FullName" >`

Comment: sorry, I meant to ask how you assigned the DataKeyNames in the Code Behind.

Comment: I tried initially to create a string array using the values of each object, which I now see was a mistake. What I should have done instead was create a string array which held the names of the parameters of the object which I wanted to be DataKeyNames. So my string array should have been `string[] dkn = {"FullName", "Name", etc etc}.

Comment: glad to hear it's working now. can you please mark this as the answer if it was helpful?